# Visual Force Page render as PDF : Table formatting

Tags: html, css, pdf, html-table, visualforce

I'm new to Visual Force. Anyone here who has an idea on how to make the data from a table as BOLD with a font-family of Arial? I already used the available font in VFPage but when I am about to declare it as BOLD. It is not working. The said problem is in the "SPAN" section and it is rendered as PDF. Hoping for your help.

Here is the VFPage I made:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" applyBodyTag="false" >

<!--CSS and HTML-->  

<head>
    <style type="text/css" media="print" >
         @page {
           size: 8.5in 13in; 
           margin-bottom: 20%;
           margin-right: 5%;   
           margin-left: 5%; 
           margin-top: 10%;                                                                                          
        }   

           .page-break {
            display:block;
            page-break-after:always;

        }

         span{               
            font-weight: bold;
             font-family: Arial Unicode MS;
        }
  </style>
</head>

<div class="page-break">

<apex:image url="{!$Resource.Logo}" width="130px" height="80px" style="padding-bottom: 30px"/>    
<table width= "100%" style="border-spacing: 15px;">
    <tr><td>This is made:</td></tr>
    <tr><td>in <span>June 2017</span> of the Schedule.</td></tr>

 </table>          
 </div>  
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope. There's no silver bullet. That font will support special characters (diacritics) and Chinese / Japanese / Korean but the downside is there's no bold version. You're welcome to upvote an idea though ;) https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DfdiAAC

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_supported_fonts.htm
- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118055/visualforce-page-as-pdf-unicode-font-bold-characters
- try this but from what I remember didn't want to work for me: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10052/visualforce-rendering-pdf-with-international-characters-and-bold-italic-arial

When all else fails - consider making your table headers in Helvetica (as `sans-serif`) and body in Arial. And pray you won't have any special characters in these headers...